# Normalizing values in gdal and mapserver

Tags: gdal, mapserver

I got several grib2 and point based data sets.

The point based datasets are showing values in hPa, while the grib2 based datasets show values in Pa. For usability its bad if the mapserver returns different units for the same parameters. gdal has a feature called GRIB_NORMALIZE_UNITS which will convert Kelvin to Celsius automatically. Is there a way to do the same for Pa to hPa? Or is there a way to tell the mapserver to divide all values by 100 before shipping them via GetFeatureInfo and in the legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible with changing gdal source code. However there is a python API (eccodes) with which you can change the values (multiply with 100) - the unit in the grib will be wrong then so the files should not be handed over to anywhere else as the data is actually wrong.